# Issues with getting layer to show as transparent until displayed with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a couple sets of layers that are all set to `position: absolute;` and they display over each other. I have `delays` and `fadeOut`'s in place so it acts in sequence. For some reason on my last display layer, if I set the `z-index` to a number that is displays, it effects all of the others, even though it is not showing. There will just be a blank section with my `background-color`, sort of like a block.

Here is the code for it. The div in question is `home-learn`. I have tried changing the z-index to be above the other layers, equal and less than equal. Each different way causes its own separate issue.

For example, right now I have it set to 1 `z-index` number less than the layer over top of that. Doing this causes it not to show, but if I make it equal or more, the `background-color` will go over-top of `blue-home-text` in the size of the wording for `home-learn`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? To see this live may help. In a comment below, I will add the live site. You will see it right on page load, after the sequence completes.

```
<div class="red">
 <div id="hand-wrap"><img src="/images/hand.png" class="hand" alt="HELLO"></div>
  <span class="hand-text">HELLO</span>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="spinner top topright"></div>
    <div class="spinner top topleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomleft"></div>
    <div class="spinner bottom bottomright"></div>
    <div class="mask q2"></div>
    <div class="mask q4"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="circle-text">We're Optimum
    <br>Designs</div>
  <div id="blue-home-text">We build beautiful, engaging sites for companies both large and small.</div>
  <!-- <div id="text-button"><span class="border-span">More About Us</span></div> -->
  <div id="home-learn">
    <div id="curtain-div"></div>
    Learn more...
  </div>
</div>

.red {
 background-color: #0085A1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.hand {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: wave 4s 1 normal forwards;
}

.hand-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 42%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: waveTxt 2s 0s 2 alternate;
  animation: waveTxt 2s 0s 2 alternate;
}

.circle {
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.spinner {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #b5f2ff;
  z-index: 10;
}

#circle-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}

#blue-home-text {
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 25%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  z-index: 99;
}

#home-learn {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin: 0 25%;*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2.3em;
  z-index: 98;
}
```

Comment: Live website: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/test_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your code I believe the following CSS should help with the laying issue. This should avoid the curtain layer from showing on top of the blue-home-text.

```
#home-learn {
   z-index: 99;
}

#blue-home-text {
   z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: No problem happy to help!